# Python recursive multiprocessing behaving linear?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class A:
    def F1(self, q, code1, code2):
        data = -1
        q.put(data)

    def F2(self, q, code1):
        q2 = Queue()
        for i in range(10):
            '''
                some processing here
            '''
            p = Process(target=self.F1, args=(q2, i, j))
            p.start()
            print(q2.get())
        p.join()

    def Handler(self):
        q = Queue()
        for i in range(10):
            p = Process(target=self.F2, args=(q, i))
            p.start()
            print(q.get())
        p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = A()
    app.Handler()
```

After executing I observed that the code executes in a linear fashion, not utilizing multiprocessing. I can't figure out the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by calling `q2.get` (for instance) in the `for` loop, you waited for each process to finish before starting another one. Your dispatchers could be changed as follows to get all 10 working in the background simultaneously.

```
def F2(self, q, code1):
    q2 = Queue()
    processes = []
    # start all of the processes
    for i in range(10):
        '''
            some processing here
        '''
        p = Process(target=self.F1, args=(q2, i, j))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    # get data for all processes. buggy because an exception in the
    # child is not caught and will cause program to hang
    for i in range(10):
        print(q2.get())
    #dispose of the processes
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

`multiprocessing` already has the `Pool` class that does the work for you and handles exceptions to boot.

Comment: Thanks, your Idea just did what I wanted.. !